# print value pointed to at by thrust iterator

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

Please see below code:

```
thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator whereToBegin = copyListOfNgramCounteachdoc.begin();
end = thrust::unique_by_key(end.first, end.first + numUniqueNgrams,end.second);
thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator end1 = end.first;
thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator iter;
for(iter = whereToBegin; iter!=end1; iter++){
    //PRINT VALUE POINTED AT BY ITERATOR
 }
```

The question is really simple. How do i print the value that `iter` points at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your host code:

```
std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
```

Just like standard containers.

Comment: Thanks. I will be obliged if you could also look at my question thrust::unique_by_key eating up last element and let me know if you see anything funny